# Question on sufficiency in proving inequalities

Tags: inequality

when proving inequalities, say if we take a statement and then go onto show that it implies another statement which is obviously true, then would this be sufficient in proving the original statement?

For example, say we have to prove:

$$\sqrt{3} < \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}$$

$$\Rightarrow 3 < 2 + \sqrt{3}$$

$$\Rightarrow 1 < \sqrt{3}$$

Which is true, but is this sufficient as the implication is the wrong way?

Could this be overcome by reversing the steps or using an if and only if argument, so:

$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \sqrt{3} < \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}} \\ & \iff 3 < 2 + \sqrt{3} \\ & \iff 1 < \sqrt{3} \end{aligned}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A correct proof using the algebraic steps in the "natural order of simplification" would be the following:

Assume $$\sqrt{3}\geq\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\ .\tag{1}$$
It follows that
$$3\geq 2+\sqrt{3}$$
and therefore that
$$1\geq\sqrt{3}\ ,$$
which we know to be false. Therefore our assumption $(1)$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right, the implication should go the other way. While using double ended implications (if and only if) would also be acceptable, even in this case it's much nicer to reverse the steps so that we still have the nice flow of the proof in which we start with something we know and use that and logical steps to show something else is true.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Objectively, the answer to your question is 'no'.  In mathematics, we say that one statement *implies* another if either the second statement is true or the first statement is false.  So, it is perfectly valid to say '$n$ is even and $n$ is odd' $\Rightarrow$ $n=17$, since the first statement is always false.  Similarly, any statment you like can be made to imply a true statement.

As an example, you could take the inequality

$$
2\le1
$$

This then implies the true statement that

$$
0\le0
$$

(Note - you could say that this inequality follows by multiplying both sides of the above equation by $0$ - that is true, but unnecessary: since $0\le0$ is true, any statement you like implies that $0\le0$, even if there isn't a nice way to get from one to the other.  Notice that the fact that $2\le 1\Rightarrow0\le0$ does not tell us anything about whether the statement '$2\le 1$' is true or not.)

You have rightly noticed that the correct way to go about this is to go the other way.  In my example, you can't start with $0\le0$ and derive the (false) inequality $2\le1$, because '$0\le0$ does not imply $2\le1$.  The following, however, is a perfectly valid mathematical deduction:

\begin{align}
1&<\sqrt{3}\\
\Rightarrow 3&<2+\sqrt{3}\\
\Rightarrow \sqrt{3}&<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}
\end{align}

Since the first statement is true, the last statement is true.  Notice that I'm not telling you how to do the question: when you're working it out, you will naturally start with the inequality $\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ and work your way backwards to $1<\sqrt{3}$ before noticing that all the implications work in reverse, but if you want to write out a mathematical *proof* that $\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$, you've got to go this way round.

Of course, as you point out, another approach is to write that:
\begin{align}
\sqrt3&<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}\\
\Leftrightarrow3&<2+\sqrt3\\
\Leftrightarrow1&<\sqrt3
\end{align}

Now you've shown that the statements $\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ and $1<\sqrt{3}$ are *equivalent* - one is true if and only if the other is.  Since the last statement is true, then so is the first one.  I would counsel against doing this for a couple of reasons, though:

1. It seems slightly ugly to show that a statement is equivalent to a statement that is obviously always true.  The only result you are really interested in establishing here is the truth of the statement $\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ - since $1<\sqrt3$ is clearly true, the reverse implication is trivial.
2. When you go on to do more advanced mathematics, you'll find that arguments where you can prove equivalence of two statements using chains of $\Leftrightarrow$ signs become rarer and rarer: you usually need a different argument to prove $P\Rightarrow Q$ than you do to prove $Q\Rightarrow P$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much for the detailed response :D